# Labels Disappearing in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, label

I have 2 labels and 2 sliders on a scene in spriteKit

when i touch a slider the label above it vanishes and i have no idea why,

```
import SpriteKit
var bg = SKSpriteNode()

class Settings: SKScene {

let button   = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.Custom) as UIButton
let statButton   = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.Custom) as UIButton
let speedLabel = SKLabelNode()
let impulseLabel = SKLabelNode()
var sliderDemo = UISlider()
var gravityDemo = UISlider()
var speedLabelValue = SKLabelNode()
var impulseLabelValue = SKLabelNode()
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
  backgroundImage()


    let height = CGFloat(view.bounds.height/2)
    let width = CGFloat(view.bounds.width/2)



// Change Bird Speed
    speedLabel.fontSize = 30
    speedLabel.text = "Change Speed:"
    speedLabel.position = CGPoint(x: width, y: height*2-60)
    addChild(speedLabel)

    sliderDemo.frame = CGRectMake(width-125, 33, 250, 100)
    sliderDemo.minimumValue = 1
    sliderDemo.maximumValue = 7
    sliderDemo.continuous = true
    sliderDemo.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    sliderDemo.value = 3.0
    sliderDemo.addTarget(self, action: "speedSlider:", forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)
    view.addSubview(sliderDemo)



// Change Bird Impulse (Gravity)
    impulseLabel.fontSize = 30
    impulseLabel.text = "Change Gravity:"
    impulseLabel.position = CGPoint(x: width, y: height*2-150)
    addChild(impulseLabel)

    gravityDemo.frame = CGRectMake(width-125, 120, 250, 100)
    gravityDemo.minimumValue = 60
    gravityDemo.maximumValue = gravMax
    gravityDemo.continuous = true
    gravityDemo.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    gravityDemo.value = gravMid
    gravityDemo.addTarget(self, action: "gravitySlider:", forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)
    view.addSubview(gravityDemo)








    let image2 = UIImage(named: "arrowright") as UIImage!
    button.frame = CGRectMake(width*1.5-37.5, height*1.51, 75, 75)
    button.setTitle("Play Game", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    button.setImage(image2, forState: .Normal)
    button.setTitleColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action: "GameSceneFunc", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    button.alpha = 1
    view.addSubview(self.button)



    // Stat Button
    let image = UIImage(named: "stats") as UIImage!
    statButton.frame = CGRectMake(width/2-37.5, height*1.5, 75, 75)
    statButton.setTitle("View Statistics...", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    statButton.setImage(image, forState: .Normal)
    statButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    statButton.addTarget(self, action: "Statistics", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    statButton.alpha = 1
    view.addSubview(self.statButton)



}









func speedSlider(sender:UISlider!)
{
    var sValue = Int32(sender.value)
    speedLabelValue.text = String(sValue)


    if (sValue == 1) {
        sValue = 7
    } else if (sValue == 2) {
        sValue = 6
    } else if (sValue == 3) {
        sValue = 5
    } else if (sValue == 4) {
        sValue = 4
    } else if (sValue == 5) {
        sValue = 3
    } else if (sValue == 6) {
        sValue = 2
    } else if (sValue == 7) {
        sValue = 1
    }

    dur1 = Double(sValue)+0.5
    dur2 = Double(sValue)+0.5


}







func gravitySlider(sender:UISlider!) {
    var sValue2 = Int32(sender.value)
    impulseLabelValue.text = String(sValue2)


    impulse = CGFloat(sValue2)


}
```

Just to clarify - When i tap the slider after going to the scene the label above it will disappear, when i touch the other slider the label doesn't disappear, whatever one i touch first the label linked to it is the one that changes

Comment: i have edited my comment Rob - Sorry was a little vague everything is now in the comment. Im not too sure about self.addchild, i have always used self. as a prefix to addChild and it has always worked

Comment: I was messing about with the Hierarchy button and i can see that the impulseLabel has a green box with a diagonal line going through it which doesn't look too promising.. Really stumped on this one

Comment: Anything else you can recommend to try?

Comment: Hmm. It's got to be something else. I notice that your above code snippet doesn't actually add the `speedLabelValue` and `impulseLabelValue` labels, but once I did that, it worked fine.

Comment: i think I'm confusing the situation with the comments and other question, but we can disregard the other question i did try to delete it but couldn't for some reason...

Right from the top - When i go to my settingsScene i have (from top to bottom)  Label1 - Slider1 - Label2 - Slider2. My problem is when i click Slider2 - Label2 will disspear then if i click Slider1 Label1 will update like it should.... and vice versa

Comment: Think it worked that time, and i hope i cleared up exactly what is happening regarding vanishing labels in my previous comment

Comment: By the way, given that I'm unable to reproduce your problem in my one-scene example, maybe the problem rests in the "when I go to my settings scene..." portion of your comment. Maybe the problem rests in something you have in the prior scene. Try creating test project with just one scene and I suspect you'll see what I did, that you can't reproduce the problem. So keep adding stuff to your stand-alone example until you actually can manifest the problem you describe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code snippet, I don't see you adding the `speedLabelValue`:

```
speedLabelValue.fontSize = 30
speedLabelValue.fontColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
speedLabelValue.text = "v"
speedLabelValue.position = CGPoint(x: width, y: height*2-120)
addChild(speedLabelValue)
```

Nor do I see you adding your `impulseLabelValue`

```
impulseLabelValue.fontSize = 30
impulseLabelValue.text = "g"
impulseLabelValue.position = CGPoint(x: width, y: height*2-210)
addChild(impulseLabelValue)
```

But, in my case, when I added those two labels, it updated fine.

I also initialize those two labels by calling the `.ValueChanged` methods manually once:

```
speedSlider(sliderDemo)
gravitySlider(gravityDemo)
```

Comment: The speedLabelValue was implemented as a secondary way of showing the user the value of the slider as i couldn't get the original way (the impulseLabel or speedLabel to update currently). i created the LabelValue variables so that i could start fresh and see were i was going wrong and if i had overlooked something, In my other question (which i tried to delete) it was happening when i transitioned scenes but i have fixed that, now it just happens on the first one which is clicked.

Comment: Fine, but nonetheless the code sample in your question is internally inconsistent (the selector methods are updating labels you haven't added to the scene). But if I added labels (as shown in my answer), those new labels are updated properly. Or, if I removed those labels and changed the selector functions to update the labels that you did add, those also were updated correctly. Bottom line, I'm unable to reproduce the problem on the basis of what's been shared with us so far, so the problem rests elsewhere. Expand your search and/or provide us a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Sorry its all getting bit much - staring at this code for hours now trying to figure this out, inside the functions i am just setting the label to the value of the slider using the `.text =` suffix     when i click on the debug hierarchy button like you suggested it seems that the labels are part of the background and do not have the boxes around them like everything else has.  surely just updating the text should work but it isn't

Comment: Yeah, I deleted that answer because that's only useful for UIKit controls. In your original rendition of this question, you made no reference to SpriteKit and I provided the tools for diagnosing typical UIKit problems.

Comment: @LukeTerzich I know it's frustrating, but you have to provide us a simplified example that manifests the problem you describe. I created a blank SpriteKit project, added your scene, removed the button stuff, just added two labels and two sliders, fixed the sliders' selector methods to update the appropriate labels and everything works fine. So the problem clearly rests elsewhere. I don't know of any Sprint equivalents to the UIKit tricks I showed you.

Comment: I have just done what you have done and it is fine, i also deleted all sliders and functions / labels and re wrote all the code - It now works fine now? You are a credit to this website and i know you should not give thanks but honestly thank you for the guidance in resolving this issue! its been annoying me for hours!